# How to install/setup mutt with Gmail on CentOS and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, email, mutt, mail-user-agent

How to setup the email client Mutt to send, receive and read email under CentOS and Ubuntu using a Gmail account as a relay

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Gmail Setup

For authentication, you'll have to do either of two things:

1. Generate an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) for your Google Account (your only option if you're using 2FA),
2. Turn on [less-secure app access](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) (not an option with 2FA)

In gmail, go click the gear icon, go to `Settings`, go to the tab `Forwarding POP/IMAP`, and click the `Configuration instructions` link in `IMAP Access` row.

Then click `I want to enable IMAP`. At the bottom of the page, under the paragraph about configuring your mail client, select `Other`. Note the mail server information and use that information for further settings as shown in the next section.

### Install mutt

#### CentOS

```
yum install mutt
```

#### Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

### Configure Mutt

Create

```
mkdir -p ~/.mutt/cache/headers
mkdir ~/.mutt/cache/bodies
touch ~/.mutt/certificates
```

Create mutt configuration file `muttrc`

```
touch ~/.mutt/muttrc
```

Open muttrc

```
vim ~/.mutt/muttrc
```

Add following configurations

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes

set imap_user = "change_this_user_name@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "PASSWORD"

set from="change_this_user_name@gmail.com"
set realname="Your Name"

set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/"
set spoolfile = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
set postponed="imaps://imap.gmail.com/[Gmail]/Drafts"

set header_cache = "~/.mutt/cache/headers"
set message_cachedir = "~/.mutt/cache/bodies"
set certificate_file = "~/.mutt/certificates"

set smtp_url = "smtps://change_this_user_name@gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:465/"

set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
```

Make appropriate changes, like `change_this_user_name` to your gmail user name and `PASSWORD` to your gmail password. And save the file.

Now you are ready to send, receive and read email using email client Mutt by simply typing `mutt`.

For the first time it will prompt to accept SSL certificates; press `a` to always accept these certificates.

Now you will be presented with your Gmail inbox.

Comment: This still works with Ubuntu and Gmail as of today, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: Works with Gmail and mutt installed via brew on OSX High Sierra as well. Frankly this should work with any normal install of mutt. Thanks Sushant!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me...the only thing I would add is that if you have 2fa enabled, you'll need to setup an application password. You can get to that in your google account settings under security.

Comment: After doing the above-mentioned steps. Mutt still says `unable to reach imap.gmail.com`. How can I narrow down the problem here?

Comment: @Prathu Please enable IMAP access, under Gmail settings.

Comment: @SushantMane I found the solution to my problem, it wasn't related to IMAP access settings. My university's network has blocked IMAP ports and hence mutt wasn't able to connect to `imap.gmail.com`. Everything worked fine after I switched to an external network.

Comment: In case you don't want to store your password in the `muttrc` file, you can simply omit the line `set imap_pass = "PASSWORD"` in the configuration file listed above and also write `set smtp_url = "smtps://change_this_user_name@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"`, mutt will prompt you to enter the password for receiving and sending emails

Answer (score 1):

a) Generate an APPLICATION-SPECIFIC PASSWORD from your Google Account

b01) Install Mutt Mail User Agent:

`apt install mutt`

b02) It ins't necessary to do any port forwarding, trigger or Virtual Server modification in your router!

b03) Generate directories as follows:

`mkdir -p ~/.mutt/cache/headers`

`mkdir ~/.mutt/cache/bodies`

`touch ~/.mutt/certificates`

b04) Use the following muttrc config:

`nano muttrc` on `.mutt` directory:

```
set from = "user@gmail.com"
set realname = "User Name"
set imap_user = "user@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "pwd"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
set postponed ="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set header_cache =~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
set smtp_url = "smtps://user@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_pass = "pwd"
set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
```